# Bootstrap 5 data-bs-toggle "collapse" prevent action with clicking button with in div

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bootstrap-5

I have a < div > with the data-bs-toggle attribute.  Within that div I have buttons

[image: Example]

The Panel will collapse when you click it, but I don't want the collapse event to trigger when you click the buttons.  How can I control this behavior.  It looks like the bs event happens before the button click event.

Within the click event for the buttons I tried adding:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

This didn't seem to have the desired effect I needed.